# How to redraw the items in CheckedListBox control?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, checkedlistbox

Currently i'm working on WindowsForms application. In that i have used checkedlistbox to display the display member of combobox column. i need to draw the display member of the combobox column instead of value member, How to change the text of the checkedListBox items.

```
internal class CheckedListBoxAdv:System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
{

public CheckedListBoxAdv()
      :base()
{ }
protected override void OnDrawItem(System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   if(this.Items.Count > 0)
   {
      if (excelFilter.displayMemberColList.ContainsKey(this.Items[e.Index].ToString()))
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(excelFilter.displayMemberColList[this.Items[e.Index].ToString()], Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
   }

}
base.OnDrawItem(e);
}
     }
```

Comment: You can use `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. Then always  value `DisplayMember` will be shown in control. You can also create a class for Items and override it's `ToString` method. Then always `ToString` of items will be shown.